# Why does my drupal 7 site think the below variables are not functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, typeerror

I put this JS code into my drupal site using  drupal_add_js. That's fine. However, jquery or drupal, thinks that var parentHeight, itemHeight, topMargin and topPosition are all not functions. 
I get this error: TypeError: $(...).parent(...).actual is not a function.
I checked my JS on js fiddle and it told me I had no errors. Also using Jquery 1.11 right now. Tried moving up and down the spectrum of Jquery releases but no luck. Can anyone help me?

```
    // Vertically center project headers in image tile
function verticalCenterHeaders() {
    $('ul.project-list li .description .text').each(function() {
        var parentHeight = $(this).parent().actual('height');
        var itemHeight = $(this).actual('height');
        var topMargin = -itemHeight / 2 + 'px';
        var topPosition = parentHeight / 2 + 'px';
        $(this).css({'top' : topPosition,'marginTop' : topMargin}).fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
```

Thanks for any help, Rebecca

Comment: `actual` is not a standard jQuery function, but you're trying to call it on a jQuery object. If you're using some plugin, say what it is. If not, well, that's the problem.

Comment: If you are using actual.js make sure you are loading it into your document after your jquery. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`actual` is not a standard jQuery function (as you can see from [the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)), but you're trying to call it on a jQuery object:

```
var parentHeight = $(this).parent().actual('height');
// Here ----------------------------^
```

jQuery does provide a `height` function:

```
var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();
```

Also `innerHeight`:

```
var parentHeight = $(this).parent().innerHeight();
```

...and `outerHeight`:

```
var parentHeight = $(this).parent().outerHeight();
```

...depending on your needs.